# How to hide output of subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, espeak

I'm using eSpeak on Ubuntu and have a Python 2.7 script that prints and speaks a message:

```
import subprocess
text = 'Hello World.'
print text
subprocess.call(['espeak', text])
```

eSpeak produces the desired sounds, but clutters the shell with some errors (ALSA lib..., no socket connect) so i cannot easily read what was printed earlier. Exit code is 0.

Unfortunately there is no documented option to turn off its verbosity, so I'm looking for a way to only visually silence it and keep the open shell clean for further interaction.

How can I do this?

Comment: could you not just call with os.system then? not ideal but shouldnt print i dont think

Comment: @JoranBeasley: os.system() will print to the console unless you redirect the shell command

Comment: no, os.system('espeak '+ text) reproduces this behavior.

Comment: @ferkulat: I updated my answer to also show the `os.system` syntax. Though it is just for illustration. Stick with subprocess

Comment: good correction ...  your right ... for some reason i remembered incorrectly thinking that os.system didnt print ...

Comment: Non 2.7 specific version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495078/how-do-you-discard-subprocess-output-in-python which allows for the perfect `subprocess.DEVNUL` solution.

Answer (score 590, accepted):

For python >= 3.3, Redirect the output to DEVNULL:

```
import os
import subprocess

retcode = subprocess.call(['echo', 'foo'], 
    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

For python <3.3, including 2.7 use:

```
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
retcode = subprocess.call(['echo', 'foo'], 
    stdout=FNULL, 
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

It is effectively the same as running this shell command:

```
retcode = os.system("echo 'foo' &> /dev/null")
```

Comment: micro neat picks: you could use `os.devnull` if `subprocess.DEVNULL` is not available (<3.3), use `check_call()` instead of `call()` if you don't check its returned code, open files in binary mode for `stdin/stdout/stderr`, usage of `os.system()` should be discouraged, `&>` doesn't work for `sh` on Ubuntu an explicit `>/dev/null 2>&1` could be used.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks for the suggestions. I actually meant to use `os.devnull` but accidentally typed it out. Also, I am sticking with the OPs use of `call` since they are not catching the possible exception `check_call` would raise. And for the `os.system` redirect, it was more just an illustration of what the effective use of the subprocess approach is doing. Not really as a second suggestion.

Comment: Don't you need to close the FNULL that you have opened?

Comment: Just a note, you can use `close_fds=True` in `subprocess.call` to close the `FNULL` descriptor after the subprocess exists

Comment: @ewino, I thought close_fds is to have inherited file descriptors closed in the forked process. Not for it to close anything on the parent side.

Comment: Can't you just put a try block arround your code and in the finally block do: FNULL.close() ? So it is always closed no matter what.

Comment: @jdi, you're probably right. I read the module's code and it looked that way, but the documentation does specify it closes the child's descriptors.

Comment: @ewino exactly.  It closes file descriptors in the child to prevent it from Inheriting all of the parent descriptors besides stdin, stdout, stderr. I don't really get why there is a conversation going on about how to close the file handle. The fact is that I only wrote the line about calling subprocess to be concise. Yes obviously you need to close any file handles you open. I just didn't think I needed to write a wider example. You can close it manually, or with a try/finally, or using a with-context.

Comment: @ewino: On `close_fds=True`,  file descriptors are closed *after* `fork()` but *before* `execvp()` i.e., they are closed in the *child* process just *before* the executable is run. [`close_fds=True` won't work on Windows if any of the streams are redirected](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0446/#inheritance-of-file-descriptors-on-windows). `close_fds` does not close files in the *parent* process.

Comment: Similar answer here, except inline and byte mode too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8529412/1695680

Comment: great answer for python 3!

Comment: Seems it's not always possible to use this.
It doesn't work on python 2.7 (windows7) with 7zip - child process (7zip) fails immediately if `stderr` is changed to `FNULL` (or `stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`). (moght be something specific to 7zip)

Comment: @industryworker3595112, it is definitely a general solution that works. I can't confirm this specifically for windows + 7zip. I'm not familiar with whatever quirks windows+7zip could introduce

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmad it's an old and primitive way of running a command that gives little control over the subprocess. The subprocess module unified all those older styles. For instance, you can't get the pid and kill the process if needed. You cant get output and the only way to control things like the output streams or env is in the command formatting.

Comment: can it be called under `subprocess.check_output()`?

Comment: @alper, sure. They are just wrappers around basically the same thing with different default options. `check_output` defaults to capturing stdout to a pipe and returning the data, which is slightly different than piping it to devnull to be discarded. You still probably want to set stderr as appropriate.

Answer (score 106):

Here's a more portable version (just for fun, it is not necessary in your case):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

try:
    from subprocess import DEVNULL # py3k
except ImportError:
    import os
    DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'wb')

text = u"René Descartes"
p = Popen(['espeak', '-b', '1'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT)
p.communicate(text.encode('utf-8'))
assert p.returncode == 0 # use appropriate for your program error handling here
```

Comment: Note that this produces a `DEVNULL` which isn't fully general, like the one provided by `subprocess`; since it's opened `wb` it can't be used for `stdin`.

Comment: @Reid: you could use `'r+b'` mode if you need it instead.

Comment: @jfs 8 years later we just do `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL`, right?

Comment: the code is Python 2/3 compatible. If you don't need Python 2, then the import: `from subprocess import DEVNULL` is enough.

Answer (score 35):

Use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) (new in python 2.7).  It will suppress stdout and raise an exception if the command fails.  (It actually returns the contents of stdout, so you can use that later in your program if you want.)  Example:

```
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.check_output(['espeak', text])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    # Do something
```

You can also suppress stderr with:

```
    subprocess.check_output(["espeak", text], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

For earlier than 2.7, use

```
import os
import subprocess
with open(os.devnull, 'w')  as FNULL:
    try:
        subprocess._check_call(['espeak', text], stdout=FNULL)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        # Do something
```

Here, you can suppress stderr with

```
        subprocess._check_call(['espeak', text], stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL)
```

Comment: More precisely, it returns the stdout. Which is great as might want to use it as well besides being able to ignore it.

Comment: I think this is more straightforward. @StudentT I think you should handle errors with CalledProcessError. `except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e` and then use `e.code` or `e.output`

Comment: this was useful for more complex `shell` commands using variables & communicating with a  `REST` service (`subprocess.run` did not work in my case)

Answer (score 33):

As of Python3 you no longer need to open devnull and can call [subprocess.DEVNULL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL).

Your code would be updated as such:

```
import subprocess
text = 'Hello World.'
print(text)
subprocess.call(['espeak', text], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Comment: Works! In addition, can swap  `stderr` with `stdout` in code above  (or append as another argument) to  suppress outputs. "Outputs" is in the title of the question and what lead me here...maybe trivial, but thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score -7):

Why not use commands.getoutput() instead?

```
import commands

text = "Mario Balotelli" 
output = 'espeak "%s"' % text
print text
a = commands.getoutput(output)
```

Comment: a) it doesn't discard input, it accumulates it in memory unnecessarily b) it breaks if `text` has quotes in it, or uses a different character encoding, or too large for a command line c) it is Unix only (on Python 2)