# How to use espeak with python

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, espeak

I want to use espeak(http://espeak.sourceforge.net) with python2.7.0-32 bit in windows7.

Additionally, I also want to save the audio files generated by espeak.

Comment: here's how you could [run `espeak` as an external subprocess in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270665/4279)

Comment: @KiritoMcSpock9733 I don't see any reason it wouldn't work  unless espeak command itself doesn't work on Windows (the Python code is portable otherwise).

Answer (score 5):

I tried to install this [package](https://launchpad.net/python-espeak) in Windows 8 but couldn't really get it in the first few attempts.

But this is what i did to get espeak to work with python

1. Download and Install espeak for Windows from [here](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/)
2. Add the `eSpeak/command-line` folder to `PATH` so that the command `espeak` is available
3. Call `espeak` commands using python module `subprocess` similar to how it is done in the example below

http://machakux.appspot.com/blog/44003/making_speech_with_python

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @Vidhuran what's curious is that after I appended the eSpeak\command_line path to PATH, the espeak commands worked fine in cmd.exe, but they didn't in the Python shell.

Comment: @KiritoMcSpock9733 How are you trying to call espeak from the python shell. You should be doing something like this
    import subprocess
    text = '"Hello World"'
    subprocess.call('espeak '+text, shell=True)

Comment: @Vidhuran Yeah I did that and it still didn't work, but after I restarted cmd.exe it worked fine (I don't know why that worked)

Answer (score 5):

Im using this at the moment which is working well...on my Raspberry Pi

```
from subprocess import call

call(["espeak","-s140 -ven+18 -z","Hello From Mike"])
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this.

```
import subprocess

def execute_unix(inputcommand):
   p = subprocess.Popen(inputcommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
   (output, err) = p.communicate()
   return output

a = "Some amazing words of wisdom."

# write out to wav file 
b = 'espeak -w temp.wav "%s" 2>>/dev/null' % a  

# speak aloud
c = 'espeak -ven+f3 -k5 -s150 --punct="<characters>" "%s" 2>>/dev/null' % a #speak aloud

execute_unix(b) 
execute_unix(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you asking exactly?

Here there is documentation:

[eSpeak Documentation](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/docindex.html)

And samples:

[eSpeak samples](http://espeak.sf.net/samples.html)

If you have a specific doubt we can help you.

Comment: I want to ask you that i want to make an application in python programming language in which user will browse a pdf or text file on his/her machine in windows(specifically) and by using espeak i want to save the text of that file into audio file and output it in a definite folder so how do i make connection between espeak and python.or espeak with some other programming language.    if you are still not clear about the problem please leave a comment.Thanks in Advance