# How to play a dynamic string with espeak in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, espeak

I am using the espeak library for text to speech conversion.I am able to generate a dynmic sound from a string to do this.

```
os.system('espeak "hello"')
```

This works. But what i need is to generate sound from a string. This is what i did

```
string='hello'
os.system('espeak string')
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19058023/771848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just interpolate the string that you want to speak into your command.

```
>>> string = "Hello"
>>> os.system('espeak "{}"'.format(string))
```

You could use the `subprocess.Popen` function if you are accepting user input for the string.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['espeak', string])
```

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen` if you're including user input.

Comment: @Blender: Yeah, that's what I would do. But, the OP used os.system. Never mind, I'll add the Popen too.

Comment: I meant without `shell=True`: `subprocess.check_call(['espeak', string])`.

Comment: The result of `'"{}"'.format(string)` will be escaped. Just `string` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use commands.getoutput() instead?

```
import commands

def espeak(string):
    output = 'espeak "%s"' % string
    a = commands.getoutput(output)


espeak("Mario Balotelli")
```