# ImportError: No module named espeak

Tags: python, python-2.7, espeak

I am trying to integrate text to speech capability in my program using espeak(windows7). I downloaded espeak 1.48.04. Path: C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\eSpeak.

Code:

```
import wx
import wikipedia
import wolframalpha
from espeak import espeak

espeak.synth("Welcome User")
```

I get the following error:

> traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "pydaGUI.py", line 4, in module
>         from espeak import espeak ImportError: No module named espeak

Comment: try `import espeak` instead of `from espeak import espeak`?

Comment: Read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18508288/742269

Comment: doesn't work, the error persists. no module named espeak

Comment: Tried this after adding path:   
import wikipedia
import wolframalpha
import subprocess
text = '"Hello" '

subprocess.call('espeak '+text,shell=True)    not gettinf the module error anymore but no sound either

Comment: Are you sure you have it installed? do `pip list` and see if you can see espeak listed

Answer (score 0):

isn't it written with a capital S....

> from eSpeak import ...

never used