# How to read output from subprocess without printing to terminal?

Tags: python, subprocess

I've searched fairly thoroughly for an answer, but haven't found any solutions to this.

I need to execute a child process only momentarily to print its version information.  If run from the command line, it's simply

```
.\bin\application.exe --version
```

and version information is printed to the terminal.  I'd like to capture that information in a string.  I've been trying out variants of

```
args = ("path\to\application.exe", "--version")
subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

with no success.  I also need this not to print the output to the terminal, if possible.  What can I do?

Comment: Is the application printing the version information to STDERR?  Try adding `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to your `Popen` call and see what happens.

Comment: Glad to help! I added an answer for better visibility for people who come across this question later.

Comment: note: if you want to discard the output then you should use [`DEVNULL`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270665/4279) instead of `PIPE` otherwise you can run out of memory if the child process generates enough output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes applications dump version information to STDERR instead of STDOUT.

You can capture both like this:

```
args = ("path\to\application.exe", "--version")
subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).communicate()[0]
```