# python text to speech with that can read variables contents

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hi all I am trying to do text to speech. I have tried a few python modules I have tried the pyttsx and system modules

I would like to know if there is a way to get either of these modules to read the contents of a variable.

```
name = bob

import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say("my name is",name)
engine.runAndWait()
```

what I am trying to do above does no work it just reads the string and quits after that. Is there a way to make this module read the string and the variable ?

same thing with system.

```
from os import system
system("say hello my name is",name)
```

Comment: Why the contradictory tags?

Comment: Which version of python are you running? If you do not know, type in `python -V`

Comment: I have a mac which comes with 2.7 by default and I also run 3.3 I usually use the python 3.3

Comment: ok, then my answer should work :)

Comment: unrelated: you could [run `espeak` that works on many platforms in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270665/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing it the wrong arguments. The second argument to [`say`](http://pyttsx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/engine.html#pyttsx.engine.Engine.say) is a name to give the utterance, not more stuff to say. Concatenate the strings to get what you want:

```
engine.say("my name is " + name, "saymyname")
```

Similarly, [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) only takes one argument. You need to build a single string to pass to it:

```
os.system("say hello my name is " + name)
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. But one other question. can i have this module read only one variable ? or can i pass in multiple variables ?

Comment: You can build a string with the contents of as many variables as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a mac, try doing this:

```
import subprocess
name = 'bob'
subprocess.call('say %s' %(name), shell=True)
```

This will call `say bob` in a terminal window, which **will** say it out loud. Or, as [user2357112 says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139394/python-text-to-speech-with-that-can-read-variables-contents/22139441#22139441), you can do the following:

```
import os
name = 'bob'
os.system("say my name is %s" %(name))
```