# How do I stop play function from printing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, printing, sox

I could not find a suitable music player for my text-based python program, as they were all based off of pygame. Thus, I resorted to use my `sox` program from python with an `os.system`. However, whenever I play a file with `play mymusic.wav`, it prints this:

```
flap.wav:
 File Size: 11.3k     Bit Rate: 257k
  Encoding: Signed PCM    
  Channels: 1 @ 16-bit   
Samplerate: 16000Hz      
Replaygain: off         
  Duration: 00:00:00.35  
In:100%  00:00:00.35 [00:00:00.00] Out:15.6k [      |      ]        Clip:0    
Done.
```

How can I stop it from printing this?

Comment: open it as a `subprocess` and redirect stdout to /dev/null

Comment: The only code is `play flap.wav`. The sox program does the rest (It is not **my** program. I got it through `brew install sox`.

Comment: @ebarr did you mean like this: `subprocess.call(['play', 'flap.wav'], stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`?

Comment: related: [How to hide output of subprocess in Python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the output can just be redirected to /dev/null like:

```
import subprocess
import os

devnull = open(os.devnull,"w")
subprocess.call(['play', 'flap.wav'], stdout=devnull)
devnull.close()
```

That will just pipe anything your call sends to stdout into `/dev/null`.