# Python - Executing code as long as a subprocess is running

Tags: python, subprocess, rsync

I would like to run a section of code as long as a forked subprocess (rsync) is running. This is how I did it in my code:

```
rsync_proc = subprocess.Popen(proc_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while rsync_proc.poll() == None:
            sys.stdout.write('\r'+ 
                rsync_progress_report(source_size_kb, dest, start)),
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(1)
```

For some reason, this causes the rsync subprocess to get stuck when it's almost finished. The while loop just continues looping with the `rsync_proc.poll()` returning `None`.
When I do run this same rsync call without the while loop code, it finishes without a problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `None` is a singleton; use `is None` instead of `== None`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain the difference in short?

Comment: `is` compares objects identities. `==` is an equility. You could define your own custom class that overrides `__eq__` method so that its instances are equal (`==`) to `None` but only `None` is `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attach `strace` to your stuck rsync child process, you'll probably see it's blocked writing to stdout.

If it's blocked writing to stdout, it's probably because the pipe is full *because you never read from it*.

Try reading from the pipe and just discarding the output - or, if you really don't want the output, don't connect it to a pipe in the first place.

Comment: That could be it, thanks! Will try at work tomorrow and let you know if that solves it.

Comment: @YechielLabunskiy: what made you use `PIPE` in the first place? You could [use `DEVNULL`, to discard output](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270665/4279).