# Start a subprocess, which is a new windows console in which an exe is started

Tags: python, windows, command-line, subprocess, return-code

I don't know if what I intend to do is even possible or reasonable, so I'm open for any suggestions.

Currently I have a script which starts *n* subprocesses of `some.exe id` which I regularly `poll()` to determine if they terminated and if so, with which errorlevel. The subprocesses are saved in a dict (key = subprocess, value = id). *n* instances of *some.exe* are kept running, each with an own id, until every id of a predefined list has been processed.

*some.exe* has no gui on it's onw, it writes the progress to the stdout, which I do not need. Now, for some reason sometimes, *some.exe* doesn't continue, as if it would wait - thus `poll()` never produces an errorlevel and `done = proc.poll() is not None` is never true. Which sooner or later leads to my dict of *n* procs, all being inactive and the overall progress is stuck.

If issued manually in a cmd, *some.exe* with an id, that shows this behaviour in the script - works perfectly fine.

Therefore my idea was to start a new cmd window from the script, which runs *some.exe* with the id, but I should still be able to `poll()` said exe.

Here's ***roughly*** what I have so far:

```
while id_list > 0:
    if len(proc_dict) < n:
        id = next_id()
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["some.exe", id], stdout=PIPE)
        proc.poll()
        proc_dict[proc] = id
    else:
        done_procs = []
        for proc in proc_dict.keys():
            done = proc.poll() is not None

            if done:
                print("returncode: "+proc.returncode)
                done_procs.append(proc)

        if done_procs:
            for p in done_procs:
                del proc_dict[p]

        time.sleep(2)
```

edit: if I `proc.communicate()[0]` in the `else:` where the `sleep` is located, *some.exe* is able to continue/finish, but as `communicate` waits for the process, it slows down the script way too much.

Comment: Is there a lot of output to stdout from some.exe?

Comment: I'd say so.. the output varies but it's about 20-100 lines or more.

Comment: Do you still get the problem if you take out `stdout=PIPE`?

Comment: I just tested it and as it seems it works without `stdout=PIPE`..! did I hit some limit there? thank you very much! Is there some other way to surpress the stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `some.exe`'s output is enough to fill the os pipe buffer, causing a deadlock. There is a warning about this in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)

If you want to discard the stdout, instead of sending it to a pipe you could instead send it to `devnull`, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11269627/659346) explains how to do that