# Interrupting the omxplayer playback in python

Tags: python, linux, video, raspberry-pi

I am trying to change the video of omx player in python based on an event. But the problem is the next video gets loaded only after the first video finishes.

```
import os
os.system('omxplayer video1.mp4')
if(flag==1):
    os.system('omxplayer video2.mp4')
```

Is there a way to interrupt video1 in middle of playback and start second video.
Note:I am working on a raspberrypi with debian wheezy and python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

[Omxplayer](http://omxplayer.sconde.net/) has keyboard controls so you could send the corresponding keystroke `q` to stop it normally before opening the next instance. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389648/how-to-open-and-close-omxplayer-python-raspberry-pi-while-playing-video) is a similar post where a person tried to achieve similar feature, it could be helpful.

Comment: Is there a way to send the keystroke in python

Comment: See the second link with the Python example and look how `Popen` is done - there the author retrieves a pipe to stdin and then just writes to it.