# Python - subprocess with Quotes and Pipe Grep

Tags: python, subprocess

im having an issue trying to get a simple grep command into python.  I want to take the output of the following command in a file or a list.

```
grep -c 'some thing' /home/user/* | grep -v :0
```

This is what I have, but its not working at all...

```
thing = str(subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-c', 'some thing', '/home/user/*', '|', 'grep', '-v', ':0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Basically I need to search files in a directory and return a result if my string is missing from any of the files in the directory.

Working Code (Thanks!!):

```
thing = subprocess.Popen(('grep -c "some thing" /home/user/* | grep -v ":0"' ),shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? why not use `glob`?

Comment: Python 3.7+: `thing = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True, universal_newlines=True)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pipe `|` is a shell feature. You have to use Popen with `shell=True` to use it.

Answer (score 2):

To emulate the shell pipeline in Python, see [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16709666/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from glob import glob
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p1 = Popen(["grep", "-c",  'some thing'] + glob(os.path.expanduser('~/*')),
           stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "-v", ":0"], stdin=p1.stdout)
p1.stdout.close()
p2.wait()
p1.wait()
```

To get output as a string, set `stdout=PIPE` and call `output = p2.communicate()[0]` instead of `p2.wait()`.

To suppress error messages such as "grep: /home/user/dir: Is a directory", you could [set `stderr=DEVNULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11270665/4279).

You could implement the pipeline in pure Python:

```
import os
from glob import glob

for name in glob(os.path.expanduser('~/*')):
    try:
        count = sum(1 for line in open(name, 'rb') if b'some thing' in line)
    except IOError:
        pass # ignore
    else:
        if count: # don't print zero counts
           print("%s:%d" % (name, count))
```