# run bash command to python script

Tags: python, bash, shell

how to run the following command in python script?

```
echo "show stat" | socat unix-connect:/var/run/haproxy/admin.sock stdio | grep webservers,BACKEND | cut -d , -f8
```

I tried this

```
import subprocess
var = subprocess.check_output(echo "show stat" | socat unix-connect:/var/run/haproxy/admin.sock stdio '| grep ' webservers,BACKEND' | cut -d , -f8', shell=True)
var=int(var)
```

but That doesn't work !

Comment: `var = subprocess.check_output("""echo "show stat" | socat unix-connect:/var/run/haproxy/admin.sock stdio '| grep ' webservers,BACKEND' | cut -d , -f8'""", shell=True)`

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911820/python-subprocess-with-quotes-and-pipe-grep

Comment: You need to pass a string, not a command.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Popen` :

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p1 = Popen(["echo", "show stat"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["socat", "unix-connect:/var/run/haproxy/admin.sock", "stdio"], stdin=p1.stdout)
p3 = Popen(["grep", "webservers,BACKEND"], stdin=p2.stdout)
p4 = Popen(["cut", "-d", ",", "-f8"], stdin=p3.stdout)
```