# Python subprocess.Popen() wait for completion

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am writing a small script to serially walk through a directory and run a command on the subdirectories therein.

I am running into a problem however with [Popen()](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) that it will walk through the directories and run the desired command without waiting for the previous one to finish. i.e.

```
for dir in dirs:
    #run command on the directory here.
```

it kicks off the command for each dir without caring about it afterwards. I want it to wait for the current one to finish, then kick off the next. The tool I am using on the directories is `Log2timeline` from SANS SIFT which takes quite a while and produces quite a bit of output. I don't care about the output, I just want the program to wait before kicking off the next.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: unrelated: to discard subprocess' output properly, see [How to hide output of subprocess in Python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use [Popen.wait](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait):

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["your_cmd"]...)
process.wait()
```

Or  [check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), [check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) which all wait for the return code depending on what you want to do and the version of python.

If you are using python >= 2.7 and you don't care about the output just use `check_call`.

You can also use [call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) but that will not raise any error if you have a non-zero return code which may or may not be desirable

Answer (score 16):

```
subprocess.check_output( ... )
```

will block ... and can be used instead of Popen

however if you are set on Popen

```
subprocess.Popen(...).communicate()
```

will also block until the process returns

Comment: neither `check_output` nor `.communicate()` would be useful here: *"[subprocess] produces quite a bit of output. I don't care about the output"*. `call()` or `check_call()` should be used instead.

Comment: ahh good point :P thats what I get for not reading ... that said ... the output is just getting tossed out in these examples anyway