# subprocess.call returns 0 when trying to run an app with arguments

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run CPU-Z with Python to save a system report in a text file. This code is calling UAC in Win10, if cmd has no admin rights and then second cmd window opens:

```
import subprocess
import ctypes
import sys

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if is_admin():
    subprocess.call(['cpuz_x32.exe', '-txt=report'])
else:
    # Re-run the program with admin rights
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, __file__, None, 1)
```

When I'm in Python interpreter, 0 is returned. However, there is no `report.txt` file created. `cpuz_x32.exe` is in the same directory from where I started interpreter.

This was on Windows10. `subprocess.call` asked for elevated cmd, so this called UAC.

Then I decided to try this code in one of my WinXP virtual machines. No UAC there. Script runned well. No problems at all. The report.txt file was created. Is this bug in Win10 cmd, subprocess or Python 3.4.3?

Comment: Have you tried calling it directly from the command line, to see whether it's a Python problem or a CPU-Z problem?

Comment: Yes, I have. It works directly from cmd in Windows, like this `cpuz_x32.exe -txt=report`

Comment: If your code just ends here, the possibility is that python interpreter ends without waiting for process to finish, and hence you don't see output. Try  this with `process = subprocess.Popen(["your_cmd"]...)
process.wait()"` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284715/python-subprocess-popen-wait-for-completion)

Comment: No change. After I enter p.wait() it returns 0 and no file is created.

Comment: @Aritesh "`subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)` Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return."

Comment: Tried in WinXP and it runs ok. The report.txt file was created. So, the code is good. It has something to do with eleveted cmd window, when you run the script without admin rights. I click `yes` in UAC but subprocess.call obviously doesn't run and has not admin rights still.