# Subprocess.Popen not running another script

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have script1.py which does some calculations and sends some emails and script2.py (is used to do some updated in a Mysql DB) which is in an infinite loop until some things are satisfied.

At the end of the calculations made on script1, I need to execute script2.py and to do this I am using `subprocess.Popen(["python", "script2.py"])` now when debugging this, I see that it goes inside script2 and it works but when the execution of script1 ends I see that the script2.py stops its execution.

Is there another module used to do this kind of things, because it's not working properly ?

**EDIT:** I need to execute script1.py in order to execute script2.py but when using subprocess.Popen() the script1 waits for the script2 to terminate the execution. I need a way to execute script2 and let it run and terminate script1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python subprocess.Popen() wait for completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284715/python-subprocess-popen-wait-for-completion)

Comment: You need to specifically wait until the command run with `popen` has completed. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284715/python-subprocess-popen-wait-for-completion)

Comment: Why dont you `import script2` and call it directly?

Comment: I don't think this is the same as the one referenced by +FlyingTeller, this one seems more appropriate but it depends what Script2 is doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624850/launch-a-completely-independent-process

Comment: @FlyingTeller I need to start an independent process and subprocess does not do that

Answer (score 1):

script_1.py:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "script_2.py"])
print("CONTROLLER TERMINATED")
```

script_2.py:

```
import time
for x in range(5):
    print("ALIVE")
    time.sleep(1)
```

[image]

After adding in `process.wait()` to script_1.py:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "script_2.py"])
process.wait()
print("CONTROLLER TERMINATED")
```

[image]