# Suppress stderr within subprocess.check_output()

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm trying to find a way to ignore the stderr stream (something similar to `2> /dev/null`):

```
output = subprocess.check_output("netstat -nptl".split())
```

What should I add to the above command to achieve this?

Comment: related: [How to hide output of subprocess in Python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575)

Comment: The above is pretty much a duplicate, except the specific method (`call` versus `check_output`).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just tell `subprocess` to redirect it for you:

```
import subprocess
    
output = subprocess.check_output(
    "netstat -nptl".split(), stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL
)
```

For python 2, it's a bit more verbose.

```
import os
import subprocess

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
    output = subprocess.check_output(
        "netstat -nptl".split(), stderr=devnull
    )
```

Comment: For Python 3: `output = subprocess.check_output("netstat -nptl".split(), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` is a right approach?

Comment: @alper: no, that redirects stderr to stdout. To *suppress* stderr, use `output = subprocess.check_output("netstat -nptl".split(), stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)`

Comment: from python 3.5 on you have also `subprocess.run()`, which should be used for newer code.

`output = subprocess.run(check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL).stdout`

Comment: @gelonida: sure, but note that this question is tagged with `python-2.7`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True. I just thought, that python 2.7 will become less and less common and that python 3 users might also stumble upon this question. You think I should delete my comment?