# prevent unexpected stdin reads and lock in subprocess

Tags: python, linux, shell, pipe, subprocess

A simple case I'm trying to solve for all situations.
I am running a subprocess for performing a certain task, and I don't expect it to ask for stdin, but in rare cases that I might not even expect, it might try to read. 
I would like to prevent it from hanging in that case.

here is a classic example:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["unzip", "-tqq", "encrypted.zip"])
p.wait()
```

This will hang forever.
I have already tried adding

```
stdin=open(os.devnull)
```

and such..

will post if I find a valuable solution.
would be enough for me to receive an exception in the parent process - instead of hanging on communicate/wait endlessly.

update: it seems the problem might be even more complicated than I initially expected, the subprocess (in password and other cases) reads from other file descriptors - like the /dev/tty to interact with the shell. might not be as easy to solve as I thought..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your child process may ask for a password then it may do it outside of standard input/output/error streams if a tty is available, see the first reason in [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)

As [you've noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33277846/4279), creating a new session prevents the subprocess from using the parent's tty e.g., if you have `ask-password.py` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Ask for password. It defaults to working with a terminal directly."""
from getpass import getpass

try:
    _ = getpass()
except EOFError:
    pass # ignore
else:
    assert 0
```

then to call it as a subprocess so that it would not hang awaiting for the password, you could use `start_new_session=True` parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'ask-password.py'],
                      stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, start_new_session=True,
                      stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

stderr is redirected here too because `getpass()` uses it as a fallback, to print warnings and the prompt.

To emulate `start_new_session=True` on Unix on Python 2, you could use `preexec_fn=os.setsid`.

[To emulate `subprocess.DEVNULL` on Python 2, you could use `DEVNULL=open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279) or pass `stdin=PIPE` and close it immediately using `.communicate()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

Popen([sys.executable, 'ask-password.py'],
      stdin=PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid,
      stderr=PIPE).communicate() #NOTE: assume small output on stderr
```

Note: you don't need `.communicate()` unless you use `subprocess.PIPE`. `check_call()` is perfectly safe if you use an object with a real file descriptor (`.fileno()`) such as returned by `open(os.devnull, ..)`. The redirection occurs before the child process is executed (after `fork()`, before `exec()`) -- there is no reason to use `.communicate()` instead of `check_call()` here.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the culprit is the direct usage of /dev/tty and such.

On linux at least, one solution is to add to the Popen call the following parameter:

```
preexec_fn=os.setsid
```

which causes a new session id to be set, and disallows reading from the tty directly. i will probably use the following code (stdin close is just in case):

```
import subprocess
import os
p = subprocess.Popen(["unzip", "-tqq", "encrypted.zip"],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
p.stdin.close() #just in case
p.wait()
```

last two lines can be replaced by one call:

```
p.communicate()
```

since communicate() closes stdin file after sending all the input supplied.

Simple and elegant it seems.

Alternatively:

```
import subprocess
import os
p = subprocess.Popen(["unzip", "-tqq", "encrypted.zip"],
                     stdin=open(os.devnull), preexec_fn=os.setsid)
p.communicate()
```

Comment: unrelated: you could use `subprocess.DEVNULL` on Python 3. I like `os.setsid` solution more (if it works), but you could also provide a pseudo-tty using [`pexpect` or `pty.openpty()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279) (your case is [the first reason described in `pexpect` docs](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)).

Comment: you can call `p.communicate()` instead of `p.stdin.close(); p.wait()` in the first example. There is no reason to call `p.communicate()` in the last example (just use `subprocess.check_call()` instead).

Comment: meta: you can [accept your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian awesome, had to look at communicate source to see it closes stdin after writing input. wonderful, thanks!

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian if i understand correctly, check_call is an option for when you don't want stdout/stderr from the process and just want notification if it failed. also a viable option - but with check_call i would have to use the setsid also I'm assuming. correct?

Comment: you don't need to look at `.communicate()` source; its [behavior is documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate): *"Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate."* -- it implies that `p.stdin` is closed otherwise you couldn't call a subprocess that  may read an unlimited input. Your examples should be: `Popen([..], stdin=PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid).communicate()` and `call([..], stdin=DEVNULL, preexec_fn=os.setsid)`

Comment: Instead of using `preexec_fn`, you can set `start_new_session=True` (Python 3.2 and up). This triggers a `setsid()` call in the new child process without the need for a cryptic-looking `preexec_fn` argument.

Comment: can't import setsid from os in python 3.7.9. any substitute?