# python asyncio gets deadlock if multiple stdin input is needed

Tags: python, git, subprocess, stdin, python-asyncio

I wrote a command-line tool to execute `git pull` for multiple git repos using python asyncio. It works fine if all repos have ssh password-less login setup. It also works fine if only 1 repo needs password input. When multiple repos require password input, it seems to get deadlock.

My implementation is very simple. The main logic is

```
utils.exec_async_tasks(
        utils.run_async(path, cmds) for path in repos.values())
```

where `run_async` creates and awaits a subprocess call, and `exec_async_tasks` runs all the tasks.

```
async def run_async(path: str, cmds: List[str]):
    """
    Run `cmds` asynchronously in `path` directory
    """
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *cmds, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, cwd=path)
    stdout, _ = await process.communicate()
    stdout and print(stdout.decode())


def exec_async_tasks(tasks: List[Coroutine]):
    """
    Execute tasks asynchronously
    """
    # TODO: asyncio API is nicer in python 3.7
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    else:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

The full code base is [here on github](https://github.com/nosarthur/gita/blob/master/gita/).

I think the problem is something like the following. In `run_async`, `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec`, there is no redirection for stdin, and the system's stdin is used for all subprocesses (repos). When the first repo asks for password input, asyncio scheduler sees a blocking input, and switches to the second repo while waiting for the command-line input. But if the second repo asks password input before the password input for the first repo is finished, the system's stdin will be linked to the second repo. And the first repo will be waiting for input forever.

I am not sure how to deal with this situation. Do I have to redirect stdin for each subprocess? What if some repos have passwordless login and some don't?

Some ideas are as follows

1. detect when password input is needed in `create_subprocess_exec`. If it does, then call `input()` and pass its result to `process.communicate(input)`. But how can I detect that on the fly?
2. detect which repos requires password input, and exclude them from async executions. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: What about disabling the password prompt with a trick like `GIT_ASKPASS=echo` and retrying the commands that failed in a sequential way?

Comment: Without a proper analysis I guess from your description the problem might be in access to the terminal. While each process has its own stdin that can be redirected, the whole session has only one (controlling) terminal and if a password is read directly from the terminal, there is no way to send it from a program. If this happens to be the case and there is no other way around the password entry, I would try to provide a pseudoterminal to each process expecting a password. I have never done that before. See man forkpty (C language!). Everything I wrote is about Unix/Linux only.

Comment: This one might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277452/prevent-unexpected-stdin-reads-and-lock-in-subprocess

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the default configuration, when a username or password is needed `git` will [directly access the `/dev/tty` synonym](https://github.com/git/git/blob/53f9a3e157dbbc901a02ac2c73346d375e24978c/compat/terminal.c#L17-L54) for better control over the 'controlling' terminal device, e.g. the device that lets you interact with the user. Since subprocesses by default inherit the controlling terminal from their parent, all the git processes you start are going to access the same TTY device. So yes, they'll hang when trying to read from and write to the same TTY with processes clobbering each other's expected input.

A simplistic method to prevent this from happening would be to give each subprocess its own session; different sessions each have a different controlling TTY. Do so by setting `start_new_session=True`:

```
process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
    *cmds, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, cwd=path, start_new_session=True)
```

You can't really determine up-front what git commands might require user credentials, because git can be configured to get credentials from a whole range of locations, *and* these are only used if the remote repository actually challenges for authentication.

Even worse, for `ssh://` remote URLs, git doesn't handle the authentication at all, but leaves it to the `ssh` client process it opens. More on that below.

How Git asks for credentials (for anything but `ssh`) is configurable however; see the [gitcredentials documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials). You could make use of this if your code must be able to forward credentials requests to an end-user. I'd not leave it to the git commands to do this via a terminal, because how will the user know what specific git command is going to receive what credentials, let alone the issues you'd have with making sure the prompts arrive in a logical order.

Instead, I'd route all requests for credentials through your script. You have two options to do this with:

- Set the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable, pointing to an executable that git should run for each prompt.

  This executable is called with a single argument, the prompt to show the user. It is called separately for each piece of information needed for a given credential, so for a username (if not already known), and a password. The prompt text should make it clear to the user what is being asked for (e.g. `"Username for 'https://github.com': "` or `"Password for 'https://someusername@github.com': "`.
- Register a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/api-credentials#_credential_helpers); this is executed as a shell command (so can have its own pre-configured command-line arguments), and one extra argument telling the helper what kind of operation is expected of it. If it is passed `get` as the last argument, then it is asked to provide credentials for a given host and protocol, or it can be told that certain credentials were successful with `store`, or were rejected with `erase`. In all cases it can read information from stdin to learn what host git is trying to authenticate to, in multi-line `key=value` format.

  So with a credential helper, you get to prompt for a username and password combination *together* as a single step, and you also get more information about the process; handling `store` and `erase` operations lets you cache credentials more effectively.

Git fill first ask each configured credential helper, in config order (see the [`FILES` section to understand how the 4 config file locations](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES) are processed in order). You can add a new one-off helper configuration on the `git` command line with the `-c credential.helper=...` command-line switch, which is added to the end. If no credential helper was able to fill in a missing username or password, then the user is prompted with `GIT_ASKPASS` or [the other prompting options](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#_requesting_credentials).

For SSH connections, git creates a new `ssh` child process. SSH will then handle authentication, and could ask the user for credentials, or for ssh keys, ask the user for a passphrase. This again will be done via `/dev/tty`, and SSH is more stubborn about this. While you can set a `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable to a binary to be used for prompting, SSH will only use this [if there is no TTY session and `DISPLAY` is also set](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272506/can-i-get-ssh-to-use-an-askpass-program-even-if-it-was-run-from-a-terminal).

`SSH_ASKPASS` must be an executable (so no passing in arguments), and you won't be notified of the success or failure of the prompted credentials.

I'd also make sure to copy the current environment variables to the child processes, because if the user has set up an SSH key agent to cache ssh keys, you'd want the SSH processes that git starts to make use of them; a key agent is discovered through environment variables.

So, to create the connection for a credential helper, and one that also works for `SSH_ASKPASS`, you can use a simple synchronous script that takes the socket from an environment variable:

```
#!/path/to/python3
import os, socket, sys
path = os.environ['PROMPTING_SOCKET_PATH']
operation = sys.argv[1]
if operation not in {'get', 'store', 'erase'}:
    operation, params = 'prompt', f'prompt={operation}\n'
else:
    params = sys.stdin.read()
with socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect(path)
    s.sendall(f'''operation={operation}\n{params}'''.encode())
    print(s.recv(2048).decode())
```

This should have the executable bit set.

This then could be passed to a git command as a temporary file or included pre-built, and you add a Unix domain socket path in the `PROMPTING_SOCKET_PATH` environment variable. It can double as a `SSH_ASKPASS` prompter, setting the operation to `prompt`.

This script then makes both SSH and git ask your UNIX domain socket server for user credentials, in a separate connection per user. I've used a generous receiving buffer size, I don't think you'll ever run into an exchange with this protocol that'll exceed it, nor do I see any reason for it to be under-filled. It keeps the script nice and simple.

You could instead use it as the `GIT_ASKPASS` command, but then you wouldn't get valuable information on the success of credentials for non-ssh connections.

Here is a demo implementation of a UNIX domain socket server that handles git and credential requests from the above credential helper, one that just generates random hex values rather than ask a user:

```
import asyncio
import os
import secrets
import tempfile

async def handle_git_prompt(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(2048)
    info = dict(line.split('=', 1) for line in data.decode().splitlines())
    print(f"Received credentials request: {info!r}")

    response = []
    operation = info.pop('operation', 'get')

    if operation == 'prompt':
        # new prompt for a username or password or pass phrase for SSH
        password = secrets.token_hex(10)
        print(f"Sending prompt response: {password!r}")
        response.append(password)

    elif operation == 'get':
        # new request for credentials, for a username (optional) and password
        if 'username' not in info:
            username = secrets.token_hex(10)
            print(f"Sending username: {username!r}")
            response.append(f'username={username}\n')

        password = secrets.token_hex(10)
        print(f"Sending password: {password!r}")
        response.append(f'password={password}\n')

    elif operation == 'store':
        # credentials were used successfully, perhaps store these for re-use
        print(f"Credentials for {info['username']} were approved")

    elif operation == 'erase':
        # credentials were rejected, if we cached anything, clear this now.
        print(f"Credentials for {info['username']} were rejected")

    writer.write(''.join(response).encode())
    await writer.drain()

    print("Closing the connection")
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()

async def main():
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as dirname:
        socket_path = os.path.join(dirname, 'credential.helper.sock')
        server = await asyncio.start_unix_server(handle_git_prompt, socket_path)

        print(f'Starting a domain socket at {server.sockets[0].getsockname()}')

        async with server:
            await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Note that a credential helper could also add `quit=true` or `quit=1` to the output to tell git to not look for any other credential helpers and no further prompting.

You can use the [`git credential <operation>` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential) to test out that the credential helper works, by passing in the helper script (`/full/path/to/credhelper.py`) with the git `-c credential.helper=...` command-line option. `git credential` can take a `url=...` string on standard input, it'll parse this out just like git would to contact the credential helpers; see the documentation for the full exchange format specification.

First, start the above demo script in a separate terminal:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python3.7 git-credentials-demo.py
Starting a domain socket at /tmp/credhelper.py /var/folders/vh/80414gbd6p1cs28cfjtql3l80000gn/T/tmprxgyvecj/credential.helper.sock
```

and then try to get credentials from it; I included a demonstration of the `store` and `erase` operations too:

```
$ export PROMPTING_SOCKET_PATH="/var/folders/vh/80414gbd6p1cs28cfjtql3l80000gn/T/tmprxgyvecj/credential.helper.sock"
$ CREDHELPER="/tmp/credhelper.py"
$ echo "url=https://example.com:4242/some/path.git" | git -c "credential.helper=$CREDHELPER" credential fill
protocol=https
host=example.com:4242
username=5b5b0b9609c1a4f94119
password=e259f5be2c96fed718e6
$ echo "url=https://someuser@example.com/some/path.git" | git -c "credential.helper=$CREDHELPER" credential fill
protocol=https
host=example.com
username=someuser
password=766df0fba1de153c3e99
$ printf "protocol=https\nhost=example.com:4242\nusername=5b5b0b9609c1a4f94119\npassword=e259f5be2c96fed718e6" | git -c "credential.helper=$CREDHELPER" credential approve
$ printf "protocol=https\nhost=example.com\nusername=someuser\npassword=e259f5be2c96fed718e6" | git -c "credential.helper=$CREDHELPER" credential reject
```

and when you then look at the output from the example script, you'll see:

```
Received credentials request: {'operation': 'get', 'protocol': 'https', 'host': 'example.com:4242'}
Sending username: '5b5b0b9609c1a4f94119'
Sending password: 'e259f5be2c96fed718e6'
Closing the connection
Received credentials request: {'operation': 'get', 'protocol': 'https', 'host': 'example.com', 'username': 'someuser'}
Sending password: '766df0fba1de153c3e99'
Closing the connection
Received credentials request: {'operation': 'store', 'protocol': 'https', 'host': 'example.com:4242', 'username': '5b5b0b9609c1a4f94119', 'password': 'e259f5be2c96fed718e6'}
Credentials for 5b5b0b9609c1a4f94119 were approved
Closing the connection
Received credentials request: {'operation': 'erase', 'protocol': 'https', 'host': 'example.com', 'username': 'someuser', 'password': 'e259f5be2c96fed718e6'}
Credentials for someuser were rejected
Closing the connection
```

Note how the helper is given a parsed-out set of fields, for `protocol` and `host`, and the path is omitted; if you set the git config option `credential.useHttpPath=true` (or it has already been set for you) then `path=some/path.git` will be added to the information being passed in.

For SSH, the executable is simply called with a prompt to display:

```
$ $CREDHELPER "Please enter a super-secret passphrase: "
30b5978210f46bb968b2
```

and the demo server has printed:

```
Received credentials request: {'operation': 'prompt', 'prompt': 'Please enter a super-secret passphrase: '}
Sending prompt response: '30b5978210f46bb968b2'
Closing the connection
```

Just make sure to still set `start_new_session=True` when starting the git processes to ensure that SSH is forced to use `SSH_ASKPASS`.

```
env = {
    os.environ,
    SSH_ASKPASS='../path/to/credhelper.py',
    DISPLAY='dummy value',
    PROMPTING_SOCKET_PATH='../path/to/domain/socket',
}
process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
    *cmds, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, cwd=path, 
    start_new_session=True, env=env)
```

Of course, how you then handle prompting your users is a separate issue, but your script now has full control (each `git` command will wait patiently for the credential helper to return the requested information) and you can queue up requests for the user to fill in, and you can cache credentials as needed (in case multiple commands are all waiting for credentials for the same host).

Answer (score 4):

General speaking, the recommended way to feed password to git is through "credential helpers" or `GIT_ASKPASS`, as pointed out by the [answer of Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55521308/6238076), *but for Git+SSH, the situation is complicated* (more discussion below). So it'd be difficult to set this up correctly across OS.
If you just want a quick patch to your script, here is the code that works in both Linux and Windows:

```py
async def run_async(...):
    ...
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec( *cmds, 
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, 
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, 
        start_new_session=True, cwd=path)
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate(password + b'\n')
```

The parameter `start_new_session=True` will set a new SID to the child process so that it got assigned a new session [which have no controlling TTY by default](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html). 
Then SSH will be forced to read the password from the `stdin` pipe.
On Windows, `start_new_session` seems to have no effect (there is no concept of SID on Windows AFAIK).

Unless you plan to implement a Git-credential-manager (GCM) in your project "gita", I won't recommend to feed any password to Git at all (the [unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)). Simply set `stdin=asyncio.subprocess.DEVNULL` and pass `None` to `process.communicate()`. This will force Git and SSH to use the existing CM or abort (you can handle the error later). 
Moreover, I think "gita" doesn't want to mess up with the configuration of other CMs, such as [GCM for windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/blob/master/Docs/Askpass.md). Thus, do not bother to touch the `GIT_ASKPASS` or `SSH_ASKPASS` variables, or any `credential.*` configuration. It's the user's responsibility (and freedom) to setup a proper GCM for each repo. Usually the Git distribution includes a GCM or an ASKPASS implementation already.

### Discussion

There is a common misunderstanding to the problem: Git doesn't open the TTY for password input, SSH does! Actually, other ssh-related utilities, such as `rsync` and `scp`, share the same behavior (I figured this out the hard way when debugging a SELinux related problem a few months ago). See the appendix for verification.

Because Git calls SSH as a sub-process, it cannot know whether SSH will open TTY or not. The Git configurables, such as `core.askpass` or `GIT_ASKPASS`, will **not** prevent  SSH from opening `/dev/tty`, at least not for me when testing with Git 1.8.3 on CentOS 7 (detail in the appendix). There are two common cases that you should expect a password prompt:

- Server requires password authentication;
- For public-key authentication, the private key storage (in a local file `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or PKCS11 chip) is password protected.

In these cases, ASKPASS or GCM won't help you on the deadlock problem. You have to disable the TTY.

You may also want to read about the environment variable [`SSH_ASKPASS`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html#ENVIRONMENT). It points to an executable that will be called when the following conditions are met:

- No controlling TTY is available to the current session;
- Env. variable `DISPLAY` is set.

On Windows, for example, it defaults to `SSH_ASKPASS=/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass`. This program comes with the [main-stream distribution](https://gitforwindows.org/) and the official [Git-GUI](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-gui/git-gui--askpass) package.
Therefore, on both Windows and Linux desktop environments, if you disable TTY by `start_new_session=True` and leave the other configurables unchanged, SSH will automatically popup a [separate UI window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34396390/6238076) for password prompt.

#### Appendix

To verify which process opens the TTY, you can run `ps -fo pid,tty,cmd` when a Git process is waiting for password.

```
$ ps -fo pid,tty,cmd
3839452 pts/0         \_ git clone ssh://username@hostname/path/to/repo ./repo
3839453 pts/0             \_ ssh username@hostname git-upload-pack '/path/to/repo'

$ ls -l /proc/3839453/fd /proc/3839452/fd
/proc/3839452/fd:
total 0
lrwx------. 1 xxx xxx 64 Apr  4 21:45 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 xxx xxx 64 Apr  4 21:45 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 xxx xxx 64 Apr  4 21:43 2 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------. 1 xxx xxx 64 Apr  4 21:45 4 -> pipe:[49095162]
lr-x------. 1 xxx xxx 64 Apr  4 21:45 5 -> pipe:[49095163]

/proc/3839453/fd:
total 0
lr-x------. 1 xxx xxx 64 Apr  4 21:42 0 -> pipe:[49095162]
l-wx------. 1 xxx xxx 64 Apr  4 21:42 1 -> pipe:[49095163]
lrwx------. 1 xxx xxx 64 Apr  4 21:42 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 xxx xxx 64 Apr  4 21:42 3 -> socket:[49091282]
lrwx------. 1 xxx xxx 64 Apr  4 21:45 4 -> /dev/tty
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a simple solution suggested by @vincent, i.e., disable any existing password mechanism by setting the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable, run async on all repos, and re-run the failed ones synchronously.

The main logic changes to

```
cache = os.environ.get('GIT_ASKPASS')
os.environ['GIT_ASKPASS'] = 'echo'
errors = utils.exec_async_tasks(
    utils.run_async(path, cmds) for path in repos.values())
# Reset context and re-run
if cache:
    os.environ['GIT_ASKPASS'] = cache
else:
    del os.environ['GIT_ASKPASS']
for path in errors:
    if path:
        subprocess.run(cmds, cwd=path)
```

In `run_async` and `exec_async_tasks`, I simply redirect error and return the repo `path` if subprocess execution fails.

```
async def run_async(path: str, cmds: List[str]) -> Union[None, str]:
    """
    Run `cmds` asynchronously in `path` directory. Return the `path` if
    execution fails.
    """
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *cmds,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        cwd=path)
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
    stdout and print(stdout.decode())
    if stderr:
        return path
```

You can see [this pull request](https://github.com/nosarthur/gita/pull/54/files) for the complete change.

### Further Update

The PR above resolves the problem when https type remote requires username/password input, but still has problem when ssh requires password input for multiple repos. Thanks to @gdlmx's comment below.

In version 0.9.1, I basically followed @gdlmx's suggestion: disable user input completely when running in the async mode, and the failed repos will run the delegated command again using `subprocess` serially.

Comment: Have you tested this solution? I think it won't work because without `start_new_session=True` SSH will try to open `/dev/tty`. See my answer. There's another pitfall: `GIT_ASKPASS` will overwrite  `core.askPass` in the Git config file and probably mess up with other credential manager for Git.

Comment: I made a few local repos pointing to a private github repo using https type remote. It seems to work. You can test it out using the gita version 0.8.9

Comment: I mean it will not work for repo using SSH. Maybe you can test it with this URL `git@github.com:nosarthur/gita.git`. Use password protection to your private key and disable key-agent. SSH will prompt for the password to unlock your private key.

Comment: You are right. I setup password for ssh private key and the input is messed up again. With `start_new_session=True`, it works. Thanks very much!