# Getting live output from asyncio subprocess

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to use Python asyncio subprocesses to start an interactive SSH session and automatically input the password. The actual use case doesn't matter but it helps illustrate my problem. This is my code:

```py
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        'ssh', 'user@127.0.0.1',
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.STDOUT,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    # This loop could be replaced by async for, I imagine
    while True:
        buf = await proc.stdout.read()
        if not buf:
            break
        print(f'stdout: { buf }')
```

I expected it to work something like asyncio streams, where I can create two tasks/subroutines/futures, one to listen to the `StreamReader` (in this case given by `proc.stdout`), the other to write to StreamWriter (`proc.stdin`).

However, it doesn't work as expected. The first few lines of output from the ssh command are printed directly to the terminal, until it gets to the password prompt (or host key prompt, as the case may be) and waits for manual input. I expected to be able to read the first few lines, check whether it was asking for password or the host prompt, and write to the StreamReader accordingly.

The only time it runs the line `print(f'stdout: { buf }')` is after I press enter, when it prints, obviously, that "stderr: b'Host key verification failed.\r\n'".

I also tried the recommended `proc.communicate()`, which isn't as neat as using StreamReader/Writer, but it has the same problem: Execution freezes while it waits for manual input.

How is this actually supposed to work? If it's not how I imagined, why not, and is there any way to achieve this without resorting to some sort of busy loop in a thread?

PS: I'm explaining using ssh just for clarity. I ended up using plink for what I wanted, but I want to understand how to do this with python to run arbitrary commands.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166973/sending-a-password-over-ssh-or-scp-with-subprocess-popen and similar questions; the problems you are facing are not specific to asyncio. The ssh binary does not write the password prompt to stdout, it accesses the TTY for the current process group directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a problem specific to asyncio. The `ssh` process does not interact with the `stdin` and `stdout` streams, but rather accesses the [TTY device](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) directly, in order to ensure that password entry is properly secured.

You have three options to work around this:

- Don't use `ssh`, but some other SSH client, one that doesn't expect to a TTY to control. For asyncio, you could use the [`asyncssh` library](https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/). This library directly implements the SSH protocol and so doesn't require a separate process, and it accepts username and password credentials directly.
- Provide a [pseudo-tty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) for SSH to talk to, one your Python program controls. The [`pexpect` library](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/) provides a high-level API that does this for you and can be used to fully control the `ssh` command.
- Set up an alternative password prompter for ssh to use. The `ssh` program can let *something else* handle password entry if there is no TTY, via the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable. Most versions of `ssh` are quite [picky about when they'll accept `SSH_ASKPASS` however](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/272506), you need to set `DISPLAY` too, use the `-n` command-line switch for `ssh` *and* use the [`setsid` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setsid.1.html) to run `ssh` in a new session, disconnected from any TTY.

  I've previously described how to use `SSH_ASKPASS` with asyncio in an [answer to a question about `git` and `ssh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55521308).

The path of least resistance is to use pexpect, as it supports asyncio natively (any method that accepts `async_=True` can be used as a coroutine):

```py
import pexpect

proc = pexpect.spawn('ssh user@127.0.0.1')
await child.expect('password:', timeout=120, async_=True) 
child.sendline(password_for_user)
```

Answer (score 5):

If anyone else landed here for a more generic answer to the question, see the following example:

```py
import asyncio

async def _read_stream(stream, cb):  
    while True:
        line = await stream.readline()
        if line:
            cb(line)
        else:
            break

async def _stream_subprocess(cmd, stdout_cb, stderr_cb):  
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*cmd,
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    await asyncio.gather(
        _read_stream(process.stdout, stdout_cb),
        _read_stream(process.stderr, stderr_cb)
    )
    return await process.wait()


def execute(cmd, stdout_cb, stderr_cb):  
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    rc = loop.run_until_complete(
        _stream_subprocess(
            cmd,
            stdout_cb,
            stderr_cb,
    ))
    loop.close()
    return rc

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    print(execute(
        ["bash", "-c", "echo stdout && sleep 1 && echo stderr 1>&2 && sleep 1 && echo done"],
        lambda x: print("STDOUT: %s" % x),
        lambda x: print("STDERR: %s" % x),
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here demonstration of live output. 
Briefly, run bash process -> with stdin pass an 'ls' command -> async read result from the stdout

```py
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        '/bin/bash', '-i', 
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.STDOUT,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    proc.stdin.write(b'ls \r\n')
    await proc.stdin.drain()  
    
    try:
        while True:
            # wait line for 3 seconds or raise an error
            line = await asyncio.wait_for( proc.stdout.readline(), 3 )\
            print(line)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
```

Using this technique I was not able to enter server with ssh and "password", 
I stacked with the error "bash: no job control in this shell" after command 'ssh -tt user@localhost '

Comment: That's an interesting approach, if only I could get it to properly emulate the console. I'll see what I can find

Comment: @David there are problems with stdin and ssh because it uses /dev/tty, probably it could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340366/how-to-make-ssh-receive-the-password-from-stdin

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `AsyncSSH` library? (which uses python's asyncio framework). Seems like this is what you're looking for.

```py
import asyncio, asyncssh, sys

async def run_client():
    async with asyncssh.connect('localhost', username='myuser', password='secretpw') as conn:
        result = await conn.run('ls abc', check=True)
        print(result.stdout, end='')

try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_client())
except (OSError, asyncssh.Error) as exc:
    sys.exit('SSH connection failed: ' + str(exc))
```

It also has support for ssh keys with `client_keys` param. Check the [documentation](https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#client-examples). There are many examples for interactive input, i/o redirect, etc.

Comment: I actually looked into this library to see if I could copy its method, however it has its own implementation, so it doesn't interact with the system's shell and therefore I can't use a similar method.

Answer (score 1):

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import create_subprocess_shell
from asyncio.subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT
import sys

async def main():
    # create a subprocess in asyncio and connect its stdout to the stdin of another subprocess


    p1 = await create_subprocess_shell("python myfile.py",
                                       stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    while True:
        if p1.stdout.at_eof():
            break
        stdout = (await p1.stdout.readline()).decode()
        if stdout:
            print(f'[stdout] {stdout}')
    await p1.wait()
```