# python issue with output from Popen stdout=Pipe

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl, pipe, popen

I'm new to python, sorry if I'm missing something "obvious".

Currently I'm working on a script to generate TLSA records for DNSSEC.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def makeTLSA():
    der_cert_proc = Popen(['openssl', 'x509','-in','/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem','-outform','DER'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    der_cert_output = der_cert_proc.communicate()[0].strip()

    return der_cert_output

print makeTLSA()
```

This currently only prints out the cert in DER format. But the output is different to calling

`openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem -outform DER`

But if I change it to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def makeTLSA():
    der_cert_proc = Popen(['openssl', 'x509','-in','/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    der_cert_output = der_cert_proc.communicate()[0].strip()

    return der_cert_output

print makeTLSA()
```

It outputs the same as

`openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem`

Python is 2.7.5 on Centos 7 box.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Which kind of output do you want, and specifically how does it differ from what you're getting? P.S. answer by editing the question.

Comment: unrelated: don't set `stderr=PIPE` unless you want to capture it. [Redirect to devnull if you want to discard the output instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279)

Comment: check the exit code (`der_cert_proc`) and the error output (the second result from `.communicate()`).

Comment: It works now. Just had to change this:
`return der_cert_output+'\r'`
Now the result is the same as calling the openssl commands in bash

Comment: So you have to add `\r`? But you've just called strip on the string (which removes whitespace such as `\r`). Maybe just don't call strip on the string?

Comment: It appears you only stated your observations. What, exactly, is your question?

Answer (score -1):

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

`communicate()` returns a tuble with stdout and stderr, maybe the command writes some part of the response to stderr.

You can check this using both

```
der_cert_output = (der_cert_proc.communicate()[0].strip() + 
                   der_cert_proc.communicate()[1].strip())
```

Or by dropping stderr on the command line :
openssl .... 2> /dev/null

Comment: note: it is pointless to call `.communicate()` more than once -- `.communicate()` waits for the process to exit. To get  both stdout and stderr, set `stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE` and store the returned values: `stdout_output, stderr_output = der_cert_proc.communicate()`