# Start/Stop Apache via Python script

Tags: python, apache, service, subprocess

On a RHEL 6.7 server running Python 2.6.6 I am trying to start and stop the Apache webserver as an unprivileged user in a Python script.

The command I am using is "sudo service httpd " where parameter is "start", "stop" or "status".

```
p = subprocess.Popen("sudo service httpd start", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This line alone does not work. Adding a

```
p.communicate()
```

lets the commands work as desired. Can somebody tell me why?

**UPDATE:**
The sudoers file contains a line that allows my user to run these commands passwordless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither code works (with and without `.communicate()`).

You should use  instead (assuming passwordless `sudo` for these commands):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call("sudo service httpd start".split())
```

The reasons:

1. `subprocess` functions do not run the shell by default and therefore the string is interpreted as a name of the command: you should use a list to pass multiple command-line arguments on POSIX
2. `Popen()` starts the command and returns immediately without waiting for it to finish i.e., it may happen before httpd is started. Assuming `Popen()` call is fixed, `.communicate()` waits for the child process to terminate and therefore it returns after httpd is started (whether it was successful or not).

Comment: The code definitely works with `.communicate()` and does not without. `shell=True` or `shell=False`makes no difference in my case. The weird thing for me is why Apache won't stop or start when I do not call `.communicate()`.

Comment: @Ronzo: there is no way the code in your question works on a POSIX system such as RHEL. It works if you call `.split()` as in my answer (or  if you pass `shell=True` that you should not do here).

Comment: As I stated above, the code definitely works when I call `.communicate()` and does not when it is not called. It makes no difference if I call `subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'service', 'httpd', 'start'], Shell=False, ...)` or `subprocess.Popen('sudo service httpd start', Shell=True, ...)`

Comment: @Ronzo: do you understand that  the code in your question *differs* from the both variants in your last comment? The code **in your question** does not work. period. Unrelated: Python is a case-sensitive language. Anyway, copy-paste  **as is** the code from my answer. If you need to discard the output then also [use `DEVNULL`, not `PIPE`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279)

Comment: I posted the code passage from my memory because I was not sitting in front of the machine. The code I am using is: `p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` where `cmd`is the start command with which I am starting various applications on a server. If `cmd="sudo service httpd start"` it only works after i call `p.communicate()`. 

I am aware of case sensitivity and have realized that `check_call` is a completely different function.

I am just wondering why the command to start Apache does not work without calling `.communicate()`.

Comment: `check_call()` is just `Popen()` + `.wait()` call. Now that you understand the first reason in my answer, read the second one.

Comment: Ok, but when using just `Popen` shouldn't Apache start anyway despite from the fact that `Popen` is not waiting for the process to terminate? The command `sudo service httpd start`has already been issued when `Popen` was called, right? Does calling `Popen` alone prevent it from terminating in its usual manner?

Comment: @Ronzo:  add `time.sleep(1)` (for the test), to see that `Popen()` is not the issue. The issue *might* be what happens *after* your main script exits e.g., whether SIGHUP is sent. There is no reason not use `check_call()` here that waits for `sudo` to return and works regardless of what happens after your parent script exits.

Comment: Thank you very, very much. You pointed me to my scripts' problem. My script exited before the command could complete and I did not realize that this happened.

Answer (score 0):

There are different reasons for that to happen:
1. the user is in sudoers and configured to not insert password.

2. sudo remembers your password for some time (depending on your system configuration), see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37299/how-does-sudo-remember-you-already-entered-roots-password

does it work in a brand new terminal session?

Comment: sudoers is configured to allow this command passwordless:
`myuser ALL = NOPASSWD:/sbin/service httpd *`

Behaviour is exactly like I wrote above. Without the communicate line the command does not work, with that line it works as desired.