# Proper way to close a file object used as stdout argument for Popen

Tags: python

In my script, I redirect stdout to a file as below:

```
with open(logFileName, 'w') as fp:
  proc = Popen([myexe], stdout=fp)
  # proc.wait() # I don't want to block until process completes.
```

I understand that the fp would be closed even before the process completes.
Thus my program does not work as expected.

If I do a wait(), it will work but I don't want to block.

I am wondering what is the right way to do this. Is a separate thread the only way? Surprisingly, I could not find an answer through google through this requirement should be a very common one.

**Update:** I see that it was not working for a different reason. It works fine even though the file object would be closed even before the process completes. Still not sure if this is right way to do.

Comment: Just do not use a `with` statement?

Answer (score 1):

use subprocess:

```
import subprocess

with open(logFileName, 'w') as fp:
    p = subprocess.Popen( [myexec], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
    fp, error_msg = p.communicate()
```

Comment: I don't want to block until the process terminates. Do I need to look into threads?

Comment: See the answer on my question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314475/how-to-make-subprocess-only-communicate-error