# Python suppress shell output

Tags: python, shell, dev-null

My Python script is calling a shell command via os.system as:

```
os.system('sudo ifdown wlan0 &> /dev/null')
```

If I run this command without Python, the output is suppressed, in Python, however, it still prints the output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try using `subprocess` as described here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269575/how-to-hide-output-of-subprocess-in-python-2-7

Answer (score 8):

When you use `os.system`, the shell used is `/bin/sh`. On many operating systems, `/bin/sh` is not `bash`. The redirection you are using, `&>`, is not defined by POSIX and will not work on some shells such as `dash`, which is `/bin/sh` on Debian and many of its derivatives. The following should correctly suppress the output:

```
os.system('sudo ifdown wlan0 > /dev/null 2>&1')
```