# Running shell commands sequentially in one shell with subprocess

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I am having difficulties running a series of sequential commands using the subprocess module, i need to do this so a python program can call in an installation of a cv virtualenv and then run another python program (that needs to be run within the virtualenv)

This is the command string i run from terminal, you can see it contains multiple commands that run in sequence until the creation of the cv virtual env:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper && sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/pip && export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs && source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && source ~/.bashrc && mkvirtualenv cv
```

Running this in the terminal returns me  something like this:

```
(cv) name@computer:~$
```

from that i can run my python scripts that need the openCV

my code so far is this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

cmd1 = 'sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper'
cmd2 = 'sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/pip'
cmd3 = 'export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs'
cmd4 = 'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'
cmd5 = 'source ~/.bashrc'
cmd6 = 'mkvirtualenv cv'
cmd7 = 'cd /script path'
cmd8 = 'python novo.py'


final = Popen("{}; {}; {}; {}; {}; {}; {}; {}".format(cmd1, cmd2,cmd3,    cmd4, cmd5, cmd6, cmd7, cmd8), shell=True, stdin=PIPE, 
      stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)

stdout, nothing = final.communicate()
log = open('log', 'w')
log.write(stdout)
log.close()
```

And the errors in log look like this:

```
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
/bin/sh: 1: mkvirtualenv: not found
```

How can i achieve a terminal like execution ?
again, sequence is crucial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /bin/sh: 1: source: not found

`shell=True` uses `/bin/sh` by default. `source` shell builtin hints at bash. Pass `executable='/bin/bash'`.

btw, you could use a multiline string literal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from subprocess import check_call, DEVNULL, STDOUT

with open('log', 'wb', 0) as file:
   check_call("""set -e -x
{python} -mpip install --user virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
rm -rf ~/.cache/pip
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /path/to/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source ~/.bashrc
mkvirtualenv cv
cd /script path
{python} novo.py
""".format(python=sys.executable),
              shell=True, executable='/bin/bash',
              stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=file, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
```

Or save the command into a separate bash script and run the script instead.

`DEVNULL` is Python 3 feature—it is easy to emulate it on Python 2 too: [`DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279).

Comment: Hello J.F. Sebastian, thank you for your answer, i changed the code on my python script as you suggested, but now when i execute it gives an error "File "programa.py", line 3, in <module>
    from subprocess import check_call, DEVNULL, STDOUT
ImportError: cannot import name DEVNULL"

i am really new to this kind of operations, my knowledge stays on python and opencv, dont know how to properly work with this kind of calls and bash files.

Comment: i dont really understand how shebangs work but i changed it to pyhton2, it returns  a 'CalledProcessError', you can check out the code and error on this image if it not too much trouble http://postimg.org/image/f6dfdaucr/

Comment: My answer fixes one issue: `source: not found`. If you have another issue; you should ask it as a separate question.