# Running subprocess in threads interferes with keyboard input

Tags: python, subprocess, python-curses

I've been working on some code that uses `subprocess.checkoutput` to execute commands on a remote server through ssh:

```
   subprocess.check_output(['ssh', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no',
        '-i', 'key.pem', self.pDNS,
        'python script.py', html.replace('&', '\&'), '"
        {0}"'.format(ua.random)], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

This command is run by a number of threads communicating with different servers with little to no shared resources and works fine as far as I've noticed.

However, on top of this code, I've used `curses` to write a rudimentary UI for me to monitor what my code is doing. I'm able to input commands using keyboard in a way similar to VIM or EMACS. However, I've noticed that when my code is executing the subprocess line above, keyboard input becomes very unreliable and sporadic, requiring make many repeated key presses for it to register in the program.

Is this because of some issues with subprocess playing nice with the `threading` library? If not, does anyone know what might be causing this problem?

Comment: you should explicitly separate input of the main process and subprocesses by specifying  parameter `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` (or `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` for processes demanding input)

Comment: update: `subprocess.DEVNULL` was introduced in python-3.3, so, likely, `PIPE` is the only option for earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks, that suggest works.

Comment: unrelated: 1- you should pass the remote command as a single string e.g., `'/usr/bin/python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" a "b c"'`.  2- if you don't need the output; use `check_call(cmd, stdin=DEVNULL,stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)` 3- use `pipes.quote(html)`, to escape shell-metacharacters

Comment: @user3159253: it is simple to [emulate `subprocess.DEVNULL` on  earlier Python versions `DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279)