# Subprocess Popen problem with terminate shell script

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, popen, kill

I have a little problem with understand what is going on with my code.
I have a lot of lines in my code so i decided to simulate my problem with shorter version.
Im using raspberry pi 4, flirone on rapsbian.

```
import sys
import os

import time
import subprocess

global shellscript
#global pid

def subprocess_settings():
       
    shellscript = subprocess.Popen(["/home/pi/Desktop/init_flir.sh"], close_fds=True)
    #shellscript = subprocess.Popen(["/home/pi/Desktop/init_flir.sh", "&> /dev/null"], stdin=None, stdout=None, close_fds=True)
    #pid = shellscript.pid
    
    
try:

    x = 1
    
    while True:
        if x == 0:
        
            sys.exit()            
            
        elif x == 1:

            print("Yas, x=1")
            time.sleep(2)
            subprocess_settings()
            time.sleep(5)
            print("Driver test is in background mode")
            time.sleep(2)
            print("Close process")
            subprocess.Popen.kill(shellscript)
            x=0
             
    
except KeyboardInterrupt:

    subprocess.Popen.kill(shellscript)
```

and my .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pi/github/flirone-v4l2
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=0,0 video_nr=1,2,3
sudo ./flirone ~/github/flirone-v4l2/palettes/Iron2.raw
```

I want to run my .sh file. It has to work in background. I need to terminate this with 2 ways, first one from keyboard and second inside my elif.

At the end i need to hide terminal output from .sh file.

What im doing wrong??
Is this is a problem with global variables?

[image]

How to fix this to work properly?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: you never define `shellscript` you just call it `global shellscript`

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: yes right, i had problems to copy from vnc viewer. It was short error so i decided to make a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works properly, as i wanted. In flirone driver i runned `./flirone` and opened 1 process from `subprocess.Popen` and 2 additional processes in flirone code. I checked this running command `sudo ./flirone ~/github/flirone-v4l2/palettes/Iron2.raw` and `ps aux | grep flirone` . I used `pidof flirone` command to check main ID. When im killing this process everything works as should be and other processes ends too.

```
import sys
import os
import signal
import time
import subprocess

def subprocess_kill():
      
    pidof = subprocess.check_output("pidof flirone", shell=True)
    time.sleep(1)

    subprocess.check_output("sudo kill -9 %s " % (pidof), shell=True)
    
     
try:

    x = 1
    
    while True:
        if x == 0:
        
            sys.exit()            
            
        elif x == 1:

            print("x=1")
            time.sleep(2)
            os.chdir("/home/pi/github/flirone-v4l2")
            shellscript = subprocess.Popen("sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=0,0 video_nr=1,2,3", shell=True)
            shellscript2 = subprocess.Popen("sudo ./flirone ~/github/flirone-v4l2/palettes/Iron2.raw", shell=True)
            time.sleep(5)
            print("Driver test is in background mode")
            time.sleep(2)
            print("Close process")

            subprocess_kill()

            x=0

except KeyboardInterrupt:

    print("hey")
```

When i deleted killing method from `except KeyboardInterrupt` processes ends too.

If you want to hide output of subprocess u can use:

```
FNULL = open(os.devnull, "w")
shellscript2 = subprocess.Popen("sudo ./flirone ~/github/flirone-v4l2/palettes/Iron2.raw", shell=True, stdout=FNULL)
```

More: [How to hide output of subprocess in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269575/how-to-hide-output-of-subprocess-in-python-2-7)

[Subprocess python 2.7 lib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)