# Python code to check if service is running or not.?

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I am using python2.7 to check if a service is running or not. I have made my own service and placed it inside `/etc/init.d`. I have a raspberry on which I am using it.

Now to normally check the status of service, we can do:

```
service my_service status
```

But how can I get the status of service from the python code.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply by using [os.system()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system). You then get the return code of the execution; *0* means running, *768* stopped

```
>>> import os
>>> stat = os.system('service sshd status')
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  sshd.service
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-10-05 09:35:14 IDT; 29s ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
  Process: 620 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 634 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─634 /usr/sbin/sshd
>>> stat
0  <--  means service is running

>>> os.system('service sshd stop')
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  sshd.service
0  <-- command succeeded

>>> os.system('service sshd status')
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  sshd.service
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2017-10-05 09:41:58 IDT; 10s ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
...
768 <-- service not running
```

The return code is the one returned from the execution. From the *[service](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/8/service/)* manpage:

> EXIT CODES
>          service calls the init script and returns the status returned by it.

So it's up to the init script executed. You can safely say **any return code other than 0 means the service is not running.**

You can either check *if the process is running instead* using:

```
>>> os.system('ps aux | grep sshd | grep -v grep | wc -l')
2
>>> os.system('ps aux | grep sshd123 | grep -v grep | wc -l')
0
```

Comment: You're *almost* there. You need to get the status in the code, not just show it to the user.

Comment: Hi I did what you said. But I get `768` in output.

Comment: `768` means service is not running

Comment: @Vinny where can I find all the service return codes.?

Comment: @SAndrew it is up to the init script. You can safely assume `0` means running, anything else not running.

Comment: @Vinny Thankyou. Sometimes what happens is the service goes into Active(exited) status and the status code remains 0. Is there any other code for active(exited) state.

Comment: @SAndrew you can check if the process is actually running;  I've added an example

Answer (score 41):

I might be a few years late to answer this.. but here is an easy solution I've found

```
import os  # I think it's better to use subprocess for this. but quick code for example

status = os.system('systemctl is-active --quiet service-name')
print(status)  # will return 0 for active else inactive.
```

Answer (score 15):

Little bit off-topic answer here (for python3).

In python3 you can use [pystemd](https://github.com/facebookincubator/pystemd) for this purpose. It talks with systemd via it's dbus API, so it's better than just executing `systemctl` and parsing it's output.

```
from pystemd.systemd1 import Unit
unit = Unit(b'my_service.service')
unit.load()
print(unit.Unit.SubState)
```

P.S.
It's better to use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead of using os.system().

Answer (score 9):

Using subprocess :

```py
import subprocess

stat = subprocess.call(["systemctl", "is-active", "--quiet", "ssh"])
if(stat == 0):  # if 0 (active), print "Active"
    print("Active")
```

Also, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596929/11100735) that explains well why use subprocess instead of os.system

Comment: This is the best answer in 2022, I think. Super-simple and reliable 

Answer (score -1):

You can see my code for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

def isActive(daemon):
    command = "systemctl is-active " + daemon + " > tmp"
    os.system(command)
    with open('tmp') as tmp:
        tmp = tmp.read()
        if "active" in tmp:
            os.remove('tmp')
            return 1
    return 0


sshd = "sshd"

print(isActive(sshd))
```

Comment: What are the benefits of your proposed approach over the existing answers?

Comment: Hello @Jeremy Caney: thank you for reminding me. I just give another approach and if someone searching google for solutions they will have another choice.

Answer (score -5):

The first thing you need to do is define what you mean by running:

- systemd gives you a ok status
- process is running/shows up in PS
- things actually work, ie can get a web page or ssh into box on local host

Then write something that preforms your test or find a tool that works for you